# How to draw a shape on the map fragment by touching it using google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello everyone,

I am using Google map V2 and I have to draw a shape on the map fragment by touching it.
  i.e if I rotate my fingers on the map a shape should be generated.
  I am getting problem because Google mapV2 does not provide lat ,long when we touch the
  map. I have no need to click on MapV2 so click listener is not useful for me.

So please share any idea or code to get the latitude and longitude from the map by
  touching it. So that I would draw a shape by touching the map.

Comment: check the Google map v2 example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: [How to draw free hand polygon in Google map V2 in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GoogleMap` doesn't have a touch listener, so you'll have to override `onTouchEvent` for the parent view of your `MapFragment`.  Once you have the screen coordinates of your touch event, you can get the Lat/Long by using `Projection` (Doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection)).   Simply do

`LatLng coords = mapFragment.getMap().getProjection().fromScreenLocation(point);`

Where `point` is a [`Point`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) describing the location of your touch event.

Once you have the `LatLng` describing your touch event, you can draw shapes using either `Circle` or `Polygon`.  Google's tutorial on drawing shapes will do a better job of explaining it than I could: [Shapes - Google Maps v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I have done it using the map's OnMapClickListener:

```
private boolean drawing = false;
private Polygon polygon;
private List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();

public class AreasFragment extends mapFragment implements GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    points.add(point);
    if(!drawing) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.flag))
                .anchor(0.2f, 1.0f)
                .position(point));

        PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
                .strokeWidth(2)
                .fillColor(0x80000000)
                .add(point);
        polygon = map.addPolygon(rectOptions);
        drawing = true;
    }
    else {
        polygon.setPoints(points);
    }
  }
}
```